# Add extra origins and behaviours in extsting cloudfront distribution using aws cli

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

From aws web console I am able to add extra origins and behaviors to my existing CloudFront distribution.
But I want to do the same from aws cli.

Comment: There is no specific command for updating/adding origin in cloudfront, you need to make update-distribution call , get distribution config first, add whatever you want to add, make update-distribution with new json and you'll get new etag.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudfront/update-distribution.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Download existing config:

aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id DISTR_ID > config.json

2. Alter JSON to whatever you need. Remove the following in the beginning of the file:

```
{
    "ETag": "ETAG_NUMBER",
    "DistributionConfig":
```

and a closing `}` in the end of the file. Save the file.

3. Update the distribution:

```
aws cloudfront update-distribution --id DISTR_ID --if-match ETAG_NUMBER --distribution-config file://config.json
```

Mind that ID and Etag differ.